# How to handle multiply operations for large number within a member function in following sample code

Tags: c++, oop

I was following a tutorial and an assignment to calculate a volume of a box. for that purpose, following program is written.

```
class Box
{
private:
    int length{ 0 }, breadth{ 0 }, height{ 0 };

public:
    Box() {};
    Box(int l, int b, int h) :length{ l }, breadth{ b }, height{ h } {};
    Box(Box& B) :length{ B.length }, breadth{ B.breadth }, height{ B.height } {};
    ~Box() {}

    int getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }
    int const getBreadth() { return breadth; }
    int const getHeight() { return height; }
    long long const CalculateVolume() { return static_cast<long long> (length * breadth * height);}

    bool operator<(Box& bx)
    {
        return (CalculateVolume() < bx.CalculateVolume());
    };

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Box& bx)
    {
        out << bx.length << " " << bx.breadth << " " << bx.height;
        return out;
    }
};



int main()
{
    Box bx1(1039, 3749, 8473);
    std::cout << "Volume = " << bx1.CalculateVolume() << std::endl;


    // Define the values
    int value1 = 1039;
    int value2 = 3749;
    int value3 = 8473;

    // Multiply the values together
    long long result = static_cast<long long>(value1) * value2 * value3;

    // Output the result
    std::cout << "Result of multiplication: " << result << std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

in here, Volume is calculated incorrectly and following output is given.

```
Volume = -1355615565
```

but if I multiply the three values, I was able to get the correct values.

```
Result of multiplication: 33004122803
```

Seems like the value is exceeded the maximum value of the data type but I'm not able to find out the true reason. what is the issue in `CalculateVolume()` member function of the Box class. Any hints is welcome.

Comment: Your typecast in calculating your volume is not going to protect you from overflows (it happens before the cast). Make all your `int` values `std::uint64_t` or even `double` if values can get really large (though you might end up with rounding errors, doubles are not infinitely precise)

Comment: @Pepjin Kramer, correct, I updated and worked.

Comment: @PepijnKramer But why it is working for "long long result = static_cast<long long>(value1) * value2 * value3;" ? 
changing the type of length, breath, height to uint64_t is worked but it is not permitted as per the problem description.

Comment: `static_cast<long long>(value1)` will first promote `value1` to a `long long` which will then be used for the following arguments which also get promoted. It is how C++ works, but I don't like coding like that. It relies on implicit conversions and doesn't really show the intention of the program. (In fact I mostly write code that does not rely on implicit conversions... but that's a whole different discussion).

Comment: `static_cast<long long> (length * breadth * height)` calculates `length * breadth * height` as an `int`, and THEN converts that `int` to a `long long`.  If overflow occurs it will not be fixed by the conversion to `long long`.   To *explicitly* convert each variable to `long long` and multiply them to produce a `long long`, do `static_cast<long long> (length) * static_cast<long long>(breadth) * static_cast<long long>(height)`.  It is possible to do less typing by exploiting implicit conversions, but doing that correctly requires you to work to better understand rules of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first observe that in both cases the three variables are `int`s. Next we look at the two snippets of code:

- `return static_cast<long long> (length * breadth * height);`
- `long long result = static_cast<long long>(value1) * value2 * value3;`

In the first piece the calculation is fully performed in the type of the variables (`int`), and then the result is cast to `long long`. This means that the calculation is done and overflowed before the cast is done.

In the second piece `value1` is cast to `long long` first, and then the calculation is performed - but when you multiply `int` and `long long`, then the calculation is done in the larger type, and thus no overflow happens (as the result does fit in `long long`).

EDIT: Reply to comment.

The difference is in the placement of the parenthesis:
`cast(a) * b` vs. `cast(a * b)`. In your comment you still use the latter version:

```
long long const CalculateVolume() {
    long long result = static_cast<long long>(length * breadth * height);
    return result;
}
```

You could also do this:

```
long long const CalculateVolume() {
    long long temp = length;
    return temp * breadth * height;
}
```

The point is that when *at least one* operand in the multiplication is `long long`, then the entire calculation is done in that type.

Comment: {long long const CalculateVolume() { 
 long long result = static_cast<long long>(length * breadth * height);
 return result;
}}
above is not working, changing the all the int types to uint64_t was worked.